# About martingales induced by iterative processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose I have a discrete stochastic process $\{ X_i \}_{i=1,\ldots..}$ defined as, $X_{i+1} = X_i - \eta \nabla f(X_i) + \sqrt{\eta} \xi_i$ where $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi_i \sim {\cal N}(0,I_d)$ and $\eta >0$.

Feel free to make assumptions about the distribution of $X_0$ and about the nature of $f$ as might be helpful.

- Suppose $x^*$ is a global minimum of $f$. Now consider the associated sequence $Y_i = \Vert X_i - x^* \Vert^2$. Are there general conditions known when $Y_i$ a (super-)martingale - and when true can such properties be used to show convergence of the sequence to $x^*$?

  *Feel free to use any other complicated sequence of distance notions instead of $Y_i$ if you think that can be a (super-)martingale and if it can be used to prove convergence of the $X_i$ sequence!*
- Also let me ask the same questions as above for a little more complicated relationship as, $X_{i+1} = X_i - \eta g_i + \sqrt{\eta} \xi_i$ where $\mathbb{E} [ g_i  \vert {\cal F}_{i-1} ] = \nabla f(X_i)$

  OR the in-between variant,

  $X_{i+1} = X_i - \eta(\nabla f(X_i) + \theta_i) + \sqrt{\eta} \xi_i$ where $\theta_i$ is a bounded random vector independent of the previous $\theta$s and $\xi$s.
- In either of the above 3 iteration sequences are there any general theorems about when the sequence of random variables $X_i$ will converge to the global/local minimum of $f$? (even if $f$ is smooth and convex!)

  Does such a convergence when it happens will have any natural relationship to the (super-)martingale structure if true?

---

I am particularly interested in cases where $f$ is non-convex.

Comment: Are you referring to this book? https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540439325 Could you kindly suggest which chapter here do you have in mind?

Comment: (1) How can $X_i$ be a martingale if $E(X_{i+1}-X_i|X_i) = \eta \nabla f(X_i)$? (2) What is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued supermartingale? Do you mean: each coordinate is a supermartingale? (3) I very much doubt $X_i$ can ever converge if $\eta > 0$ is fixed.

Comment: So the 2nd part of my point (1) talks about the distance to optimum being a super-martingale sequence. What are the general conditions for that to be possible and when possible can that be used to prove convergence?

Comment: I have now clarified this issue in the modified point (1)

Comment: When $f=0$, $\{X_i\}_i$ is a random drift, and it does not converge. Usually, in iterative methods, the *learning rate* $\eta$ is assumed to decrease. To second @Mateusz comment, I also doubt the sequence can converge with fixed $\eta$ in general.

Comment: I guess in any case of convergence there will exist a very small value s.t if $\eta$ is below that then convergence will happen. I am expecting that the same effect will show up here. But more fundamentally I do not see the relation between the super-martingale property (which in cases is true) and if the process can converge to the global minima.